# Возвращаемое значение события

Tags: c#, события

Всем привет!

Я создал событие, на которое подписано несколько методов. Событие возвращает значение типа bool, его цель - проверить, пересекается ли один прямоугольник с другим. В процессе выполнения события возвращаемое значение события заменяется результатом выполнения следующего подписчика, и я теряю данные.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно избежать потери данных?

Comment: У вас странный способ использовать события. Вы уверены, что вам именно события нужны?

Comment: данные в событии должны быть неизменяемые, иначе вы себе просто сами сложности добавляете. Если у вас один подписчик должен передать данные другому - то это решается не через наблюдатель, а через цепочку вызовов.

Comment: Внесу ясности: у меня есть класс Игрок, и, если он делает шаг, запускается событие, которое опрашивает все непроходимые объекты - "не задевает ли вас Игрок?". Если задевает (контур Игрока пересекается с контуром объекта), то шагнуть в эту сторону запрещено. Я пытаюсь вручную создать элементарную коллизию, проще говоря...

Comment: Собственно, класс Игрока самостоятельно должен обрабатывать ответы объектов - но как их обрабатывать, если в цепочке подписчиков возвращаемое значение постоянно меняется..? Мне стоит выбрать другой способ реализации?

Comment: Ну это странная логика, сделать шаг и потом понять что его нельзя было делать. Почему не проверять можно ли сделать шаг перед тем как его сделать? Ну т.е. игрок получает команду сделать шаг, спрашивает у окружения можно ли сделать шаг в эту сторону и если можно то делает. Это мое видение, хз как там это принято в юнити или что там у вас